# How to divide a text file sectionwise using Python

Tags: python, file, split

I have a text file as below:

```
Table of Contents
1. Intro
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
     2.1.1. Subsection 1
     2.1.2. Subsection 2
  2.2. Section 2
     2.2.1. Subsection 1
     2.2.2. Subsection 2
     2.2.3. Subsection 3
     2.2.4. Subsection 4

1. Intro
blah. blah. blah

2. All Data
2.1. Section 1
2.1.1. Subsection 1
blah. blah
2.1.2. Subsection 2
Blah. Blah.

2.2. Section 2
2.2.1. Subsection 1
Blah. Blah.
2.2.2. Subsection 2
Blah. Blah.
2.2.3. Subsection 3
Blah. Blah.
2.2.4. Subsection 4
Blah. Blah.
```

And so on.

I want to extract the bottom sections and it's contents(2.1., 2.2., etc) only. I don't want to match the 'Table of Contents'. The catch here is the section names and subsection names can be same. So I'm trying to match with section numbers i.e., 2.1., 2.2., etc.
I'm trying the below but, no luck.

```
with open(output_file, 'r') as f:
    for index in range(1,11):
        section = "2." + str(index) + "\."
        self.log.info("Section : " + section)
        for key, group in it.groupby(f, lambda line: line.startswith(section)):
            if not key:
                group = list(group)
                print("Group:" + str(group))
```

Expected Output:

```
-- Section --
2.1. Section 1
2.1.1. Subsection 1
blah. blah
2.1.2. Subsection 2
Blah. Blah.

-- Section --
2.2. Section 2
2.2.1. Subsection 1
Blah. Blah.
2.2.2. Subsection 2
Blah. Blah.
2.2.3. Subsection 3
Blaah. Blaah.
2.2.4. Subsection 4
Blaah. Blah.
```

Comment: what do you get? What is `it`? You didn't define it in code. If you will read from `f` in loop then first loop will read all lines to the end of file and next loop will try to read from the end of file and it gets nothing.  You should first read all lines to memory and work with this list. Or you should move to the beginning of file in every loop - `f.seek(0)`

Comment: you use normal string, not regex, so `\.` means exactly `\.` and you search `2.1\.` instead of `2.1.`

Comment: lines have spaces at the beginning so using `line.startswith(section)` will not match. You have to remove spaces before cheking `line.strip().startswith(section)` or you should check `section in line`

Comment: what exactly result do you expect for this data? Show it in question, not in comment. Maybe you should split on empty line - `'\n\n'` - and get only parts which start with `2.` ?

Comment: or maybe you should split on `"2. "` or `"\n2. "` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code has few mistakes

- you use normal string, not regex, so you should use `.` instead of `\.`
- you read from file in loop so first loop reads all lines to the end of file and next loop start reading from the end of file and it has nothing to read. You should read all lines to list in memory and use this list. Or you have to move to the beginning of file in every loop - `f.seek(0)`
- lines starts with spaces so checking `line.startwith(section)` will not match you have to remove spaces - `line.strip().startwith(section)`
- you have to check groups which have `key` - `if key:`

Minimal working code.

```
text = '''Table of Contents
1. Intro
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
     2.1.1. Subsection 1
     2.1.2. Subsection 2
  2.2. Section 2
     2.2.1. Subsection 1
     2.2.2. Subsection 2
     2.2.3. Subsection 3
     2.2.4. Subsection 4

1. Intro
 blah. blah. blah

2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
'''

import itertools as it
import io

#with open(output_file) as f:
with io.StringIO(text) as f:   
    for index in range(1,11):
        section = f"2.{index}."
        print("Section:", section)
        f.seek(0)
        for key, group in it.groupby(f, lambda line: line.strip().startswith(section)):            
            if key:
                print('key:', key)
                group = list(group)
                print("Group:", group)
```

You didn't show expected result but I think your code gives wrong result.

```
Section: 2.1.
key: True
Group: ['  2.1. Section 1\n', '     2.1.1. Subsection 1\n', '     2.1.2. Subsection 2\n']
key: True
Group: ['  2.1. Section 1\n', '    2.1.1. Subsection 1\n']
key: True
Group: ['    2.1.2. Subsection 2\n']
Section: 2.2.
key: True
Group: ['  2.2. Section 2\n', '     2.2.1. Subsection 1\n', '     2.2.2. Subsection 2\n', '     2.2.3. Subsection 3\n', '     2.2.4. Subsection 4\n']
key: True
Group: ['  2.2. Section 1\n', '    2.2.1. Subsection 1\n']
key: True
Group: ['    2.2.2. Subsection 2\n']
Section: 2.3.
Section: 2.4.
Section: 2.5.
Section: 2.6.
Section: 2.7.
Section: 2.8.
Section: 2.9.
Section: 2.10.
---
```

If you need all in `2. All Data`  then you should rather split on `"\n2. "` and get last part

```
text = '''Table of Contents
1. Intro
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
     2.1.1. Subsection 1
     2.1.2. Subsection 2
  2.2. Section 2
     2.2.1. Subsection 1
     2.2.2. Subsection 2
     2.2.3. Subsection 3
     2.2.4. Subsection 4

1. Intro
 blah. blah. blah

2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
'''

print('---')
parts = text.split('\n2.')
print('2.' + parts[-1])
```

Result:

```
---
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
```

If you want to split on sections then in previous result you could use `split("\n  2.")`. And later you can every section split on subsections using `split("\n    2.")`

```
text = '''Table of Contents
1. Intro
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
     2.1.1. Subsection 1
     2.1.2. Subsection 2
  2.2. Section 2
     2.2.1. Subsection 1
     2.2.2. Subsection 2
     2.2.3. Subsection 3
     2.2.4. Subsection 4

1. Intro
 blah. blah. blah

2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
'''

print('- part -')
parts = text.split('\n2.')
part = '2.' + parts[-1].rstrip() 
print(part)

result = []
all_sections = part.split('\n  2.')
for section in all_sections[1:]:
    print('- section -')
    print('  2.' + section.rstrip())
    all_subsections = section.rstrip().split('\n    2.')
    result += ['    2.'+x for x in all_subsections]
    for subsection in all_subsections[1:]:
        print('- subsection -')
        print('    2.' + subsection.rstrip())
    
print('--- result ---')        
for item in result:
    print(item)
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
- part -
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
- section -
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
- subsection -
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
- subsection -
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
- section -
  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
- subsection -
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
- subsection -
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

--- result ---
    2.1. Section 1
---
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
---
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
---
    2.2. Section 1
---
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
---
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
---
```

Or you should use `regex` to split `part` on `\n\s*2.`

```
text = '''Table of Contents
1. Intro
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
     2.1.1. Subsection 1
     2.1.2. Subsection 2
  2.2. Section 2
     2.2.1. Subsection 1
     2.2.2. Subsection 2
     2.2.3. Subsection 3
     2.2.4. Subsection 4

1. Intro
 blah. blah. blah

2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
'''

print('- part -')
parts = text.split('\n2.')
part = '2.' + parts[-1].rstrip() 
print(part)
print('- end -')

import re

result = re.split('\n\s*2\.', part)
result = ['2.'+x for x in result]
for item in result[1:]:
    print(item)
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
- part -
2. All Data
  2.1. Section 1
    2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
    2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.

  2.2. Section 1
    2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
    2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
- end -

2.1. Section 1
---
2.1.1. Subsection 1
    blah. blah
---
2.1.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
---
2.2. Section 1
---
2.2.1. Subsection 1
    Blah. Blah.
---
2.2.2. Subsection 2
    Blah. Blah.
```